# Matching Fields Wrapped in Punctuation but not Single Apostrophe

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following `Regex` that I use to translate fields in SQL strings

```
string posLookBehind = @"(?<=\p{P}*)\b";
string posLookAhead = @"\b(?=\p{P}*)";
string keyword = "FieldA";
string translatedKeyword = "FldA";
string strSql = "SELECT [FieldA] FROM SomeTableA;";
strSql = Regex.Replace(
    strSql,
    baseRegexLeft + keyword + baseRegexRight,
    translatedKeyword, 
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

For some keyword `FieldA`, the above regex would replace 'FieldA' with 'FldA' in each of the following: `[FieldA]`, `[FieldA + FieldB]` et al. However, I now wish to restrict the regex. **I do not want to match** `'FieldA'` **note the single apostrophe**.

So, I have changed the regex using regex subtraction to remove `'` from the punctuation set:

```
string posLookBehind = @"(?<=[\p{P}-[']]*)\b";
string posLookAhead = @"\b(?=[\p{P}-[']]*)";
```

where the other code is the same. But this is still matching `'FieldA'`. **What am I doing wrong here?**

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the reason behind this is the the star `*` in the look behind and the look ahead, because it matches zero or more, so after matching `FieldA` it self it then checks behind for zero or more punctuations that are not apostrophes but since there is an apostrophe it just matches zero times.

You can fix this by changing the star to a plus `+`:

```
string posLookBehind = @"(?<=[\p{P}-[']]+)\b";
string posLookAhead = @"\b(?=[\p{P}-[']]+)";
```

Or if there is only a single surrounding character all the time then:

```
string posLookBehind = @"(?<=[\p{P}-[']])\b";
string posLookAhead = @"\b(?=[\p{P}-[']])";
```

Comment: +1 Huh, subtracting from classes is new to me. I guess that's C# exclusive!

Comment: @Jerry Thanks for +1. I think it is only supported in Java and .NET, at least this is what I know of.